# (Re)define a command in qutebrowser

Tags: mapping

Qutebrowser has a command `:close` to close the current window and a command `:quit`, which can be shortened to `:q`, to quit Qutebrowser, thus closing all windows.

Since I'm used to vim and to vim's tabs, I often enter `:q`, accidentally confusing it with `:close`, thus having all windows closed at once.

What I'd like to do, is to make `:q` behave as `:close` and maybe define a `:qa` command which behave as the actual `:quit` command.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can type in normal mode `:set aliases`
and then change or add aliases as you wish.
In your case you replace the command `quit` by `close` and add `"qa": "quit"`.

B.t.w. for getting the best and fastest answers regarding the qutest browser, check out the possibilities to get help on https://www.qutebrowser.org.

Comment: Wow, it was so obvious! Much better than relying on the `:q`-proof solution of setting `auto_save.session` to `true`, which I did before your definitive answer (and which is useful by itself, btw).

Comment: I avoid posting a new question for the following, tiny, off-topic question. To your knowledge is it intended that `:open \ something` opens the first result I get with `:open something`? I noticed it by chance while testing your solution.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I don't know why a backslash has that effect, but I think it does not stem from vim. Would be interesting to know though.

Comment: qutebrowser passes the search term `\ something` to DuckDuckGo, and that's DuckDuckGo-Syntax for its "I'm feeling lucky" feature.